# P MOSFET turning on before gate threshold

Tags: mosfet, supercapacitor, pmos

I was simulating a P MOSFET, and for turning a P MOSFET on we need gate to Source voltage less then its threshold voltage. as per below simulation circuit at start VGS= 0, then there is no way mosfet get turn on,because it need at least -2V as per datasheet gate thershold to turn it on. but simulation i am getting 4V arroud, whats wrong here.
[image]

Some Might say i applied voltage VDS=5V but for P MOSFET it should be negative, but i saw some circuit where they used this type of connection where R1 is just replaced by a supercap.

Answer (score 4):

Do you know that every MOSFET has a build in body diode between the drain and the source? In your case, the anode of a body diode is connected to the drain terminal and the cathode to the source terminal. And this is why your MOSFET is turn-ON.

Your circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgh9R3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The proper way to turn on the P-Channel MOSFET looks like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbGng8.png)</sup>

And now pushing the SW1 switch will Turn ON the MOSFET. 
And releasing the switch will turn-OFF the MOSFET. 
Notice that the source terminal is connected to the highest potential in the circuit. And body diode will not conduct.

Answer (score 0):

There is a diode between source and drain on MOSFETS.  It is not always drawn in the symbol, but it is there.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ7p9H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>