# mosfet circuit without get supply mosfet on, why?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, transistors, mosfet, relay

in ckt i not give gate supply and vd=12v than vs=12v

in this condition mosfet not work as switch. why this?
[image]

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/390413/p-mosfet-turning-on-before-gate-threshold/390420#390420

Comment: Could you 1) correct your text to full english snetences without abbreviations; 2) show in the circuit what exatly you did (I see only one power supply) 3) explain what you observe ("does not work as switch" - then how did it work?) and what you expected.

Comment: We don't do text-speak here.  -1 and closing.

Answer (score 1):

The R3 in your circuit is where your load is supposed to be. Not in parallel to 4 Ohm resistor which is basically a shunt.

In case you've found this schematics somewhere on a web, note that resistor symbol is often used instead of output connections to show actual load placement (and imply the resistive type of it).